# Is using the proper directory separator when handling files really necessary?

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm seeing a lot of people do something like this:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include __DIR__ . DS . 'path' . DS . 'to' . DS . 'file.php';
```

And was wondering why they would do that if everything works fine on Windows when using the `/` instead of `\`. What is the one in a million case where this is actually necessary?

Comment: For my part I'll continue to use this constant because it seems more future safe and flexible, even if Windows installations currently convert the paths magically. Not that syntax aesthetics matter but I think it can be made to look attractive:

Answer (score 0):

The reason these constants exists are for backwards compatibility, portability and re-usability.

Underlying curcumstances might change (Maybe you develop on a Windows machine, but your server is Centos? or Debian based, in which case directory separators are different.)

Or perhaps some new standard is released, changing the separators to more unified characters. In which case you would need to go back to every instance where you referenced a directory and change the separator (And God willing PHP removes some magic).

It's good coding practice to have 1 reference point to something you re-use over and over again, that may be changed.